# pair of picture environments within amsmath parentheses

Tags: amsmath, diagrams

To gain space, I am using the picture environment to draw some bit arrays. The drawing is simple, but when a pair of them is place within amsmath parentheses some spacing issue arises: the height of the parentheses is too large.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\setlength{\unitlength}{1.25ex}
\linethickness{0.25pt}
\begin{equation*}
\left(%
\begin{picture}(17,8)(0,2.5)%
\multiput(0,0)(1,0){18}{\line(0,1){8}}%
\multiput(0,0)(0,1){9}{\line(1,0){17}}%
\end{picture}
,\
\begin{picture}(8,17)(0,5.5)%
\multiput(0,0)(1,0){9}{\line(0,1){17}}%
\multiput(0,0)(0,1){18}{\line(1,0){8}}%
\end{picture}
\right)
\end{equation*}
\end{document}
```

Is there a way to control the height ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rather than shifting the baseline of the picture yourself, leave it to TeX.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation*}
\setlength{\unitlength}{1.25ex}
\linethickness{0.25pt}
\left(
  \begin{gathered}
  \begin{picture}(17,8)
  \multiput(0,0)(1,0){18}{\line(0,1){8}}
  \multiput(0,0)(0,1){9}{\line(1,0){17}}
  \end{picture}
  \end{gathered}
\, , \quad
  \begin{gathered}
  \begin{picture}(8,17)
  \multiput(0,0)(1,0){9}{\line(0,1){17}}
  \multiput(0,0)(0,1){18}{\line(1,0){8}}
  \end{picture}
  \end{gathered}
\,
\right)
\end{equation*}

\begin{equation*}
\setlength{\unitlength}{1.25ex}
\linethickness{0.25pt}
\left(
\raisebox{\dimexpr -0.5\height + 0.5\unitlength}{%
  \begin{picture}(17,8)
  \multiput(0,0)(1,0){18}{\line(0,1){8}}
  \multiput(0,0)(0,1){9}{\line(1,0){17}}
  \end{picture}%
}
\, , \quad
\raisebox{\dimexpr -0.5\height + 0.5\unitlength}{%
  \begin{picture}(8,17)
  \multiput(0,0)(1,0){9}{\line(0,1){17}}
  \multiput(0,0)(0,1){18}{\line(1,0){8}}
  \end{picture}%
}
\,
\right)
\end{equation*}

\end{document}
```

I'd do the setting of `\unitlength` and `\linethickness` inside the `equation` environment, or in the preamble.

In the second case the centering is more accurate; the parentheses don't fully cover the picture, due to TeX's mechanism for deciding the size.

[image]